# Ошибка "Свойство Connection не инициализировано"

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Pop2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter adap;
        DataSet ds;
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdb1;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection();

                con.Open();
                string dbLocation = ("C:\\MDK\\Pop2\\Pop2\baza.mdf");
                con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; User Instance=true;Integrated Security=SSPI; AttachDBFilename=" + dbLocation;
                SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString);
                adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select Name as 'Name', Mesta as 'Mesta', idSeansa as 'Id', Type as 'Type_Zala' from Kino", con);
                ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                adap.Fill(ds, "Person Details");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cmdb1 = new SqlCommandBuilder(adap);
                adap.Update(ds, "Person_Details");
                MessageBox.Show("Изменения в базе данных выполнены!",
                "Уведомление о результатах", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Изменения в базе данных выполнить не удалось!",
                "Уведомление о результатах", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ind = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(ind);
        }
    }
}
```

Это часть программы, при попытки открыть выдает ошибку: свойство `connectionstring` не инициализировано, что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `con.Open()` вы вызываете до того, как присваиваете значение свойству `ConnectionString`.

Answer (score 2):

У вас какая-то мешанина. Зачем два экземпляра SqlConnection?

```
string connectionString = "...";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select Name as 'Name', Mesta as 'Mesta', idSeansa as 'Id', Type as 'Type_Zala' from Kino", connection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds, "Person Details");
}
```

Comment: Не помогло, что делать, я плохо разбираюсь в С#, можите подробнее объяснить?